# var a, b, c = {}

Tags: javascript, object, reference, assignment-operator

I thought the syntax:

```
var a, b, c = {};
```

would mean that the three variables are separate, not references to the same {}.

Is this because {} is an object and this is the standard behavior?

So if I do:

```
var a, b, c = 0;
```

the three would indeed be separate and not references?

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: can u explain more i can't get the point

Comment: I don't get it. In your first example, `a` and `b` are `undefined`. What do you mean ?

Comment: Do you mean `var a = b = c = {};`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They shouldn't be the same, no. Only `c` will be assigned the value.

`a` and `b` would just be declared, but not initialized to anything (they'd be undefined). `c` would, as the only one of them, be initialized to `{}`

Perhaps it's clearer when written on several lines:

```
var a,      // no assignment
    b,      // no assignment
    c = {}; // assign {} to c
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var a, b, c = {};
```

This will declare 3 variables (a, b, c) but define only 1 variable (c).

```
var a, b, c = 0;
```

This will declare 3 variables (a, b, c) but define only 1 variable (c).

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you only define the last element

`a` and `b` are undefined

Answer (score 0):

`var a, b, c = {};` only defines the last var namely `c`.  it's similar to the syntax `var a = {}, b = [], c = 0;`

it's just short hand for declaring multiple vars.

Answer (score 0):

Using coma to separate variables enables to define multiple variables in the same scope more compactly. In your sample, though, only `c = {}` and `a` and `b` would be `undefined`. You could use similar construct to assign something like

```
var a = {first: 'foo'}, 
    b = {second: 'bar'}, 
    c = {third: 'foobar'};
```

which would be equal to

```
var a = {first: 'foo'}, b = {second: 'bar'}, c = {third: 'foobar'};
```

and also to

```
var a = {first: 'foo'};
var b = {second: 'bar'};
var c = {third: 'foobar'};
```

And each one would only reference to their respective object. Using comas is basically just a visual aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the three would be separate.

The comma operator evaluates the left operand, then evaluates the right operand, then returns the value of the right operand.

This makes for a nice way to declare a bunch of variables in a row if you just rely on the evaluation of the operands and don't do anything with the returned value.

`var i = 0, j = 1, k = 2;` is basically equivalent to `var i = 0; var j = 1; var k = 2`

Another use for this is to squeeze multiple operations onto one line without using `;`, like in a for loop with multiple loop variables:

`for(var x=0,y=5; x < y; x++,y--)`

Notice how both x++ and y-- can be performed on the same line.