# Assigning multiple variables from javascript regex.exec

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a work around for some code that works in Firefox but not other browsers, currently the function looks like this:

```
function capitalise(myString) {
  // Extract 1st char (b) and rest of string (c) then return it with b capitalised
  var [a, b, c] = /^(.)(.*)$/.exec(myString);
  return b.toUpperCase()+c;
}
```

Which works perfectly in Firefox but Chrome and Opera won't allow it. Can anyone suggest a decent work around?

I use the same var [ thing1, thing2, thing3 ] = regex.exec(str); syntax for various things in the script I'm writing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this would work in other browsers:

```
function capitalise(myString) {
  // Extract 1st char (b) and rest of string (c) 
  // then return it with b capitalised
  var abc = /^(.)(.*)$/.exec(myString);
  return abc[1].toUpperCase()+abc[2];
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
function capitalise(myString) {
  return myString.match(/^(.)(.+)$/)
          .slice(1)
          .reduce(function(a,b){return a.toUpperCase()+b;}
         );
}
```

Comment: I see, whilst the exec function returns an array the more finicky js engines won't allow me to declare multiple variables on the fly whilst assigning an array value to them simultaneously.

Comment: Seems like it. On the other hand, it's a bit of a weird syntax. Although it indeed works in FF, I didn't find any documentation on it. Did you discover it by accident or, if not, could you point me to any documentation on `var [a,b,c] = ...`?

Comment: Ok, leave it, found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941837/var-a-b-c, it's called *Destructuring assignment* and indeed supported only in Mozilla's JavaScript, since version 1.7.